# Adding image buttons side by side dynamically to Liner Layout whose Orientation is vertical

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

for(i=0;i<=3 ;i++) {
  ImageButton ib= new ImageButton(this);
  BitmapDrawable imagebd;
  ib.setClickable(true);
  imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + image,null,getPackageName());

  ib.setBackgroundResource(imageid);

  lyt.addView(ib);
}
```

all the images are show vertically i want it to be horizontal

Comment: add then inside a new linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Avoid setting attributes in your Java code when it can be done via XML. Try setting the `orientation` attribute in your `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ...>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
lyt.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
for(i=0;i<=3 ;i++) {
    ImageButton ib= new ImageButton(this);
    BitmapDrawable imagebd;
    ib.setClickable(true);
    imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + image,null,getPackageName());

    ib.setBackgroundResource(imageid);

    lyt.addView(ib);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

LinearLayout buttonsLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
buttonsLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

for(i=0;i<=3 ;i++)
{
    ImageButton ib= new ImageButton(this);
    BitmapDrawable imagebd;
    ib.setClickable(true);
    imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + image,null,getPackageName());

    ib.setBackgroundResource(imageid);

    buttonsLinearLayout.addView(ib);
}
lyt.addView(buttonsLinearLayout);
```

That way, you still have your main vertical linearlayout, so you can put stuff under the buttons.

EDIT:
to use it for more than 1 row, i did a simple math calc...

```
    LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

    // calculate the number of rows needed
    int numOfButtons = something you already have i guess;

    // row layout
    LinearLayout buttonsLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    ;

    for (i = 0; i <= numOfButtons; i++) {

        // for every 3 rows, create a new layout
        // and add it to the main linear layout
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            // create layout for a 3 button row
            buttonsLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            buttonsLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // add the new row with 3 buttons to the main lineal layout
            lyt.addView(buttonsLinearLayout);
        }

        ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
        BitmapDrawable imagebd;
        ib.setClickable(true);
        imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + image, null, getPackageName());

        ib.setBackgroundResource(imageid);
        buttonsLinearLayout.addView(ib);
    }


}
```

not tested, let me know if that worked for you...

Comment: this works but the thing is if their are 10 to 15 image buttons.it should fit screen width 3 images per row and next image should start at next row

Comment: every image button has the same width?